# pluralsight cours--not having the same result in Plnkr

Tags: angularjs

Im doing the AngularJS Directives Fundamentals, and I'm stuck in the first exemple.
Here is the link to see the Plnkr
[link to see the Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/J9ZpaqHQ8aPWOrYqG4w1?p=preview)
this is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" 
     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-
     beta.17/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

 <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div user-info-card></div>
 </body>
```

I'm supposed to get these result:
[image]

Please help, I'm really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

You should be loading angular before your script.

Also I think you are loading Angular 2 in there for some reason. It's completely different from AngularJS.